# JAVA GC OverheadLimit Error

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm running a JAVA program.

When i tried to run this program this programs says

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I googled and found lots of documents say I need to use -Xmx option and -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Even though I used those options still not working. ( I used -Xmx4g for more memory )

Although I turned UseGCOverheadLimit off why does that message shows up and how can I solve this problem? Is it something related with "THREAD" ? ( Cause I saw a question from this site who had same problem but problem with exception in thread "main" )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default the JVM is configured to throw this error if you are spending more than 98% of the total time in GC and after the GC less than 2% of the heap is recovered

I suspect you have lot of resource leak in your code. it would be helpful if you paste your code here so that we can take a look at it.

There are other options also to use aggressive GC etc, but would be worth looking at your code before suggesting by guess.

Comment: +1 if you have a resource leak, the more memory you give it, the more it uses up.  It is also possible it always needed 16 GB or 64 GB or something much larger in which case, setting it high enough will "fix" the problem.

Comment: Agreed +1, Also I would strongly suggest NOT TO USE the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit instead of fixing the problem you are just postponing the inevitable: the application is running out of memory and needs to be fixed. Will wait to see the code pasted in the question :)

Comment: I agree, the option is there for your protection.